# What does double-quoting in find -name do?

Tags: bash, find

I have a question about the command find in bash. I am trying to remove all directories called Cache.

This finds all the directories/files called "Cache"

```
find . -name "Cache" -print
```

but this doesn't remove them and I got a bunch of errors from find saying that "No such file or directory".

```
find . -name "Cache" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

but this works

```
find . -name Cache -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

There are no spaces or any non-alphanumeric characters. Can anyone help me understand what's going on? Thank you.

Comment: @Digital: Agreed. It is completely impossible that the second and the third code give any different result.

Comment: @DigitalRoss Probably, on the second run he already deleted everything and thus there're no errors.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with quotes. The reason you're getting "No such file or directory" is because the directory is being erased, but since you forgot to use `-prune` they're *also* getting descended into. Of course, since they no longer exist you're now getting error messages.

```
find . -name "Cache" -exec rm -rf {} \; -prune
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-depth` option to `find` is sometimes used to get rid of the "file not found" errors in an operation like this...it forces the directory contents to be processed before the directory itself.

I don't see how the quotes would have made a difference in your example.  Were they
both run against the same directory configuration, or did you try one (producing errors, and also modifying the directory structure), then try the other one?

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to check whether the directories were deleted with the quoted find command, and they were. My mistake... quotes or not actually didn't make any difference here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Double Quoting prevents some Bash expansion. For example you can find all files beginning with *Cache* by

```
find . -name "Cache*"
```

If you would remove the double quotes, `Cache*` would get expanded by Bash and only the `Cache` files in the current directory would match.

Since you do not use any such characters, you do not need to wrap the seachr term in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the `-prune`, you probably can consider this safer method

```
find . -name "Cache" -exec echo "rm -rf \"{}\"" \; > to_be_deleted.txt
```

double check `to_be_delete.txt` before doing

```
sh to_be_deleted.txt
```

Comment: Try `find -name Cache -okdir rm -rf {} \;` instead. You don't need to say "." because that's default. 'Cache' needs no masking, since there is no whitespace in it.